# A sql query with more than 2 and,3 or conditions(mysql)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to query mysql table with below condition

```
         where 
   1.      (type = 'Single Family') 
   2.   and (transaction = 'For sale'  )
   3.  and (price BETWEEN '0' and   '7500') 
   4.   and (beds >= '0' and baths >= '0')
   5.  and (city LIKE 'British columbia%' or neigh LIKE 'British columbia%' or province LIKE 'British columbia%');
```

The result should satisfy 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 conditions.

In brief:

A property which type is Single Family and it sholud be For sale and price to be in between 0 and 7500 and it's city or neigh or province like British columbia.

For that I written query like below

```
select *  
from   tablename  
where type = 'Single Family' 
    and transaction = 'For sale'  
    and price BETWEEN '0' 
    and   '7500' 
    and beds >= '0' 
    and baths >= '0'
    and city LIKE 'British columbia%' 
    or neigh LIKE 'British columbia%' 
    or province LIKE 'British columbia%';
```

It giving results that having type as not only 'Single Family' but also remaining like 'Fields','Business'..

Then I again written the query  which returned only type='Single Family' but it failed in other conditions

```
select *  
from   tablename  
where transaction = 'For sale'  
    and price BETWEEN '0' 
    and   '7500' 
    and beds >= '0' 
    and baths >= '0'
    and city LIKE 'British columbia%' 
    or neigh LIKE 'British columbia%' 
    or province LIKE 'British columbia%' 
    and type = 'Single Family';
```

How to write correct sql query for conditions I specified.

Comment: You need brackets around the ors. `and (city LIKE 'British columbia%' or neigh LIKE 'British columbia%' or province LIKE 'British columbia%') and type = 'Single Family'`

Comment: BTW, assuming that `beds` and `baths` refer to the number of beds and baths accordingly, you should use numeric literals instead of string literals - `beds > 0 and baths > 0`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select *  
from   tablename  
where transaction = 'For sale'  
    and price BETWEEN '0' 
    and   '7500' 
    and beds >= '0' 
    and baths >= '0'
    and (city LIKE 'British columbia%' 
             or neigh LIKE 'British columbia%' 
             or province LIKE 'British columbia%' 
        )
    and type = 'Single Family';
```

this will treat the or conditions as 1 clause.

Answer (score 3):

```
select *
from   tablename 
where
     transaction = 'For sale'
     and price BETWEEN '0' and '7500'
     and beds >= '0' and baths >= '0'
     and city LIKE 'British columbia%'
     or neigh LIKE 'British columbia%'
     or province LIKE 'British columbia%'
     and type = 'Single Family'
```

Is the same as:

```
select *
from   tablename 
where
     (
       transaction = 'For sale'
       and price BETWEEN '0' and '7500'
       and beds >= '0' and baths >= '0'
       and city LIKE 'British columbia%'
     )
     or neigh LIKE 'British columbia%'
     or (
       province LIKE 'British columbia%'
       and type = 'Single Family'
     )
```

Use brackets to issolate the or's.

```
select *
from   tablename 
where
     transaction = 'For sale'
     and price BETWEEN '0' and '7500'
     and beds >= '0' and baths >= '0'
     and (
       city LIKE 'British columbia%'
       or neigh LIKE 'British columbia%'
       or province LIKE 'British columbia%'
     )
     and type = 'Single Family'
```

Answer (score 2):

Since `and` has higher precedence than `or`, you should surround your `or` conditions with brackets:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   tablename  
WHERE  type = 'Single Family' AND 
       transaction = 'For sale'  AND
       price BETWEEN '0' and '7500' AND
       beds >= '0' AND
       baths >= '0' AND 
       (city LIKE 'British columbia%' OR 
        neigh LIKE 'British columbia%' OR 
        province LIKE 'British columbia%') AND
       type = 'Single Family';
```